# Change default application external device

Tags: default, shotwell

Shotwell opens when I insert a camera card.  I want it to open Nautilus.  How do you do that?  Right clicking on the device in Nautilus does not give an "open with" option.

Comment: whats your Ubuntu Version?

Comment: have you tried Default Applications from Settings?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is the version.  In Default Applications there is no option which controls what happens when an external device is installed

Comment: if its ok for you.. can you uninstall shotwell and see how its going on? later install shotwell.. just to see its controlled by shotwell or not. if yes.. we can invoke with shotwell options..

Comment: Removing Shotwell, the camera card did not open, just mounted.  Reinstalling shotwell, same as before, Shotwell opened.

Comment: Ok.. means shotwell inbuilt have something.. can you go through all available options within shotwell to disable auto open..

Comment: Nothing in Shotwell that I tried did the trick.  I made shotwell the raw developer. Disabled external editors.  Unchecked all publishing plugins.

Comment: So is it Ok now?

Comment: Just the opposite -  nothing I tried in Shotwell made any difference.  It still opens when I insert the camera card.

Comment: do you have dconf-editor installed? check the settings in it.. it may help further

Comment: No i do not have dconfig installed.  No listed in software.  used it before.  Replaced by Tweaks or another program?

Comment: no not replaced by tweaks. both are different. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install dconf-editor` once installed, open and search key word `shotwell` lot of options available.

Comment: Could not find anything in dconf that deals with this issue

Comment: hum.. what is the type of your camera card. i mean, FAT32 NTFS something like this...

Comment: card is formatted to FAT32

Comment: Hi, when i inserted my camera card, its mounting as regular USB. no auto opening.